# Angular. Restrict 'A' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I am building single page application using Angular 1.6 - component based approach, but I need to use directive to access component's DOM. Here is my module:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import locationbarComponent from './locationbar.component';
import AutocompleteBinder from './locationbar-autocomplete-binder.directive';

let locationbarModule = angular.module('locationbar', [
  uiRouter
])

  .component('locationbar', locationbarComponent)
  .directive('autocompleteBinder', () => (new AutocompleteBinder()))
  .name;

export default locationbarModule;
```

Here is my directive:

```
export default class AutocompleteBinder {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
    this.restrict = 'C';
  }
  link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      debugger;
  }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
<locationbar class="autocompleteBinder"></locationbar>
```

Dubugger fires, everything looks good, but if I change directive restriction to 'A', dubbuger is ignored:

```
export default class AutocompleteBinder {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
    this.restrict = 'A';
  }
  link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      debugger;
  }
}
```

And also:

```
<locationbar autocompleteBinder></locationbar>
```

Could someone explain such behavior? Will be appreciated for help

Comment: should be `autocomplete-binder`, html attrs are hyphen case, but the DI naming is camel case

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes you are right!